# Why does github show me "Your recently pushed branches"?

Tags: github

I fast-forwarded a couple of development branches to be up-to-date with master, and pushed them to a private repository. The private repo is owned by the client's github account and I am a collaborator.

Now, github shows me two links under "Your recently pushed branches:", each containing "Pull request" and "Compare". When I click on "Pull request" out of curiosity, it shows me:
`Oops! master  is already up-to-date with feature  Try a different branch?`. It's the same story for any other branch because they are all fast-forward updated. So what is the point of these links?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those links let you quickly compare or open a pull request from one your branch.
They're displayed when a recently pushed branch is ahead of the remote HEAD. Most of the time, the remote HEAD points to master (this can be changed by tweaking the "default branch" of the repository in the *Admin* section).

As it looks like your remote HEAD points to master, those links should not be displayed indeed. The good move would be to send a mail **support@github.com.**.

Comment: what should I do to remove that message from the UI?

Answer (score 40):

In my situation this message disappeared themself after about 2 hours.

Answer (score 4):

What I did to remove those messages was to actually create the pull request and then after that, I labeled the pull request as closed. It didn't affect my repository in any sort of way and it did remove the message.

Comment: This is absolutely not answering the initial OP question. In his case, it is not possible to create a pull request since there are no differences with the fast-forwarded branch and the master. Moreover, this is so much work resulting in so many unneeded closed pull requests in your repo for a simple informative message that will vanish on its own and that you can just ignore.

Answer (score 2):

The message will be removed after 2 hours. And this message will only be visible to the author, not all the contributors.